# captcha image cannot display inline

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

I use Captcha helper from Codeigniter.

When I echo an image on form it always pushes the next element to new line.

How can I display the input field inline with the captcha image?

```
  .captcha img
  {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
  }
</style>

<tr>
    <td height="35" align="right">กรอกรหัสภาพ</td>
    <td valign="bottom"></td>
    <td valign="bottom">
        <div class="captcha"><?php echo $captcha['image']; //this is img tag so you can style it through img ?>
        <input name="userCaptcha" type="text" value="<?php if(!empty($userCaptcha)){ echo $userCaptcha;} ?>"  style="width:80px;float:left;" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the input text field inside your `<span>` tag, see below

```
<span style="float:left;">
    <?php echo $captcha['image']; ?>
    <input name="userCaptcha" type="text" value="<?php if(!empty($userCaptcha)){ echo $userCaptcha;} ?>" class="input_zone" style="width:80px;float:left;" />
</span>
```

In case it didn't work, you can try other tag like `<div>` and update the style, see my sample

```
<div style="display:inline; float:left;">
    <?php echo $captcha['image']; ?>
    <input name="userCaptcha" type="text" value="<?php if(!empty($userCaptcha)){ echo $userCaptcha;} ?>" class="input_zone" style="width:80px;float:left;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this style:

```
.captcha{display:inline; }
```

and remove `float:left;` from inside `<input` block.

Answer (score 0):

float:left and display:line  not work at all
but ok I use

```
.captcha img
  {
     position:absolute; 
  }
```

and it work.